# Postgres SQL function with null argument produces null for simple case/when/else

Tags: postgresql

Please explain why I get:

```
select reducer('a', null);
-- null ???
```

when:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION reducer(varchar, varchar)
RETURNS varchar AS
$$
  SELECT case
    when $1 = 'DEL' or $2 = 'DEL' then 'DEL'
    when $1 = 'READ' or $2 = 'READ' then 'READ'
    else 'NEW'
  end;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' STRICT;

select reducer('a', 'b');
-- 'NEW'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because you defined the function as `STRICT` (which is the same as `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT`). Since one of the arguments is NULL, the function is not even called, and NULL is returned.

If you don't want that, run

```
ALTER FUNCTION reducer(varchar, varchar)
   CALLED ON NULL INPUT;
```

Comment: I copied definition from `create aggregate` manual and haven't noticed `strict` keyword (( Thanks!